# Correct Web.Config for Post WebMethod with AJAX

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, web-config

I can't fix major problem of my project after moved it to .NET4, code still being same but web.config is different and web method doesn't work anymore :

[Here I explained the problem of WebMethod trouble with full logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872212/ajax-call-webpage-method-doesnt-work) , simply it could not find the method. One of my thoughts about it is wrong web.config. I really need help fixing it !

My current web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="FlowWebDataProviders" type="Flow_WEB_Nemerle.Config.FlowWebProvidersSection" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
            <add name="*.vbhtml_*" path="*.vbhtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.vbhtm_*" path="*.vbhtm" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.cshtml_*" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.cshtm_*" path="*.cshtm" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.aspq_*" path="*.aspq" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.xamlx_*" path="*.xamlx" verb="*" type="System.Xaml.Hosting.XamlHttpHandlerFactory, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.xoml_*" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.svc_*" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.soap_*" path="*.soap" verb="*" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.rem_*" path="*.rem" verb="*" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="*_AppService.axd_*" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="eurl.axd_*" path="eurl.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
            <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="FlowWebSQL" connectionString="hidden for some reasons"/>
        <add name="FlowServerConnectionString" connectionString="hidden for some reasons"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <FlowWebDataProviders IzmListProviderName="sqlProvider">
        <IzmListProviders>
            <add name="sqlProvider" type="Flow_WEB_Nemerle.Config.SqlIzmListProvider" connectionStringName="FlowServerConnectionString"/>
        </IzmListProviders>
    </FlowWebDataProviders>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="ru-RU"/>
        <httpModules/>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="cError.aspx"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
                <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"/>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="/" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" name="SqlProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider " siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <compilation debug="true" explicit="true" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <pages masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" theme="Standard" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <trust level="Full"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is working old .NET2 project with lots of bugs but Web.Methods was working :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="FlowWebDataProviders" type="Flow_WEB_Nemerle.Config.FlowWebProvidersSection" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="FlowWebSQL" connectionString="hidden"/>
        <add name="FlowServerConnectionString" connectionString="hidden"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <FlowWebDataProviders IzmListProviderName="sqlProvider">
        <IzmListProviders>
            <add name="sqlProvider" type="Flow_WEB_Nemerle.Config.SqlIzmListProvider" connectionStringName="FlowServerConnectionString"/>
        </IzmListProviders>
    </FlowWebDataProviders>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="cError.aspx"/>
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="default.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
                <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"/>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="/" name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
            <providers>
                <add connectionStringName="FlowWebSQL" name="SqlProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider " siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <pages masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" theme="Standard">
   <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
     assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </controls>
  </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
            <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <location path="Items.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Administrator,User,IzmOnly"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Report.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Administrator,User,RepOnly"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
  <location path="SingleReport.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator,User,RepOnly"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="UzerControl.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Administrator"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="n;Nemerle" extension=".n" type="Nemerle.Compiler.NemerleCodeProvider, Nemerle.Compiler"/>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4"
          type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <remove name="ChartImageHandler"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

thank you even for reading my question :) That is really major problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't remove question , sorry , but I found solution here [Ajax Call WebPage Method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872212/ajax-call-webpage-method-doesnt-work) and web.config was OK ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I pay so times for finding the right answer but not find in any site . That is a very very simple answer: It is depends on parameter location in development mode and publish mode on internet. In develop mode your URL is like this Http:// localhost:portnumber/yournamesite/pagesite/parameter And location of your parameter sit on 4 position of url and when publish your site on internet on iis , your URL has become like this Http:// yoursite.com/pagesite/parameter And location of your parameter is on position number 3. ;) Excuse me for bad English speaking ;)

Answer (score -5):

Don't use jquery to call a web service from asp.net (especially with web forms). ASP.NET has much easier solutions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx

Unfortunately many people try to use the popular methodology (as in jquery here) without checking the easier built in options :)
PS. It's emperon

Comment: no, no: the developer can use either tool he chooses, ASP.NET should work according to standards!